# Windows .bat file asking to terminate y/n

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

Recently I've noticed something unusual when closing my batch application.

When I press <kbd>x</kbd> on console, it then outputs a line stating "C^Terminate batch job (Y/N): " which requires user input. Now as far as I was aware this only happens if you press/hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> so why is this occurring? Is something in the background continuously/occasionally sending key events equal to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>? Also would like to state it sometimes doesn't happen, but the majority of the time it does.

FYI I'm definitely not pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> myself.